# Developing a dashboard using Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, plotly-dash

Apologies in advance as this question is quite broad. **My overall goal is to create a web application that allows for interactive analysis of NOAA model output data.** For now, let's say the project will consist of two different dashboards: The first dashboard will take current output model data from NOAA based on user inputs (e.g., location) and display the data using interactive plotly plots. The second dashboard will be for displaying historical data from archived NOAA data.

My background is more in chemistry and science, so while I have a good understanding of data analysis packages like Pandas, I'm much newer to web dev tools such as Django. I was originally able to create my two dashboards using Plotly Dash. I saved some sample data to my local computer and used Pandas to select subsets of data that were then plotted with plotly. However, I'd like to scale this to a fully-functioning webpage and therefore need to migrate this project to a Django framework. This is where I need help.

Basically I'm trying to determine how the big-picture flow of this project would need to look. For example, below I give the workflow for a specific example in which a user selects a location and three plots are loaded for temperature, wind speed, and pressure. Can you please help me flesh this out or correct any mistakes I'm making?

1. The user inserts a certain location using a form.
2. A timeseries of weather data for the selected location is loaded from a database into a Django model* and includes windspeed, temperature, pressure, as well as any other data the observational instrument collected.

*NOTE: *I am really struggling with this aspect of the workflow. The data exists as CSVs on NOAA's webpages. So should I query these CSVs each time a user inputs a location or should I create my own SQL database these CSVs in advance? Also, is it even possible for a Django model to be a timeseries of data? In all the tutorials, model attributes are given as a single data point.*

3. The data is then loaded into Pandas and processed (for example, maybe I want the monthly averages or want to convert to different units, etc.)
4. The three plots are then created from the Pandas dataframes using plotly.
5. The plots are displayed on the webpage

As I mentioned above, I am struggling with how this process looks using Django. I think specifically my confusion arises in the use of Django Models. Once the data gets to Pandas, I'm pretty much set, but it's Step 2 and the workflow for querying the data and loading it into a model that's confusing me.

Again, sorry for how broad this question is. Any advice at all is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have a long list of steps here so it's impossible to seriously answer. But you're on the right path, start building some of these steps and ask here on the ones you can't crack. Just ask a more focused problem so that we can help

Comment: Yeah I figured it was a bit too broad. I'll keep pushing and come back at a later stage. Thanks for the support!